# Charpit's method - locally unique

Tags: partial-differential-equations

http://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2014/3078/40/B5b2.pdf At the bottom of page 2 in these notes they give the condition for solving the equations uniquely for $p_0$ and $q_0$, but where do the $\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_0}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_0}$ come from in this equation for uniqueness? I understand if $F=0$ were of the form $Ap_0 + Bp_0 = ...$ as it would just be a linear system of two equations for $p_0$ and $q_0$ and would follow from linear algebra theory, but otherwise I don't see why. Is it a consequence of the inverse function theorem? Also how do we show this is equivalent to the data curve not being tangent to the rays/characteristics? My lecturer claimed this is because $\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_0}$ = $\frac{dx}{dt}$, and everything works out if this is true, but I would have though $\frac{\partial F}{\partial p_0}$ = $\frac{dx(0)}{dt}$?

Answer (score 0):

Condition (2.14) is the prerequisite of the implicit function theorem applied on the system (2.13). As to the non-tangent property, this comes from (2.7).